# Scala Iterable and IterableLike differences and uses

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What are the differences between [Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable) and [IterableLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.IterableLike) ?

Also what are the *appropiate* or *intended* uses of each ?

Namely, how the following methods would differ in the kinds of accepted collections in the arguments ?

```
def f[A](c: Iterable[A]) = c.foreach(print)
f: [A](c: Iterable[A])Unit

def g[A,B](c: IterableLike[A,B]) = c.foreach(print)
g: [A, B](c: scala.collection.IterableLike[A,B])Unit
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between a "trait" and a "template trait"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599937/what-is-the-difference-between-a-trait-and-a-template-trait)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterable` just composes together several traits, including `IterableLike`. I think this is mostly an implementation detail; some methods are put on `IterableLike` more as a matter of library organization than reflecting any real distinction. I'm not aware of any classes which implement `IterableLike` and don't implement `Iterable` (and the converse is impossible because `Iterable` extends `IterableLike`); I'd be interested to hear of any. So as far as I know, your methods would behave the same.

I would recommend always using `Iterable` (unless you're working on the internal implementation of the scala standard library).